# How do you array a curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

When I try adding an array modifier to a curve, it says that it "Cannot apply constructive modifiers on curve." I'm making a bezier curve which will be followed by the camera to make it seem as if the camera is "Walking", like a 1st person 3D animation. I made the first sequence of the curve but have no way of making it longer without individually modelling every single step throughout the walk path.

Is there any way to sort of array the curve to avoid this?

Comment: Like an array modifier? You may need to apply it in order for it to work. Als make sure Merge is enabled

Comment: You can convert your curve to a mesh (`Alt`+`C`) and then add some modifiers like Array

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any really easy way to do this, but I found one which is far easier than modelling each individual step / bump.

First I modeled two full cycles of the sequence -- middle, low, middle, high, middle, low, middle, high. This sequence mimicks a bobbing motion of the camera, as if it is walking in 1st person. Then, I deleted the last 3 vertices of the curve, leaving only middle, low, middle, high, middle.

I turned on snapping to vertices, tabbed into edit mode, selected the whole curve, and duplicated it. I then used vertex locking to lock the very first vertex of the duplicated curve to the very last vertex of the original curve, essentially moving the entire curve where I wanted it. Then, I deleted the very first vertex of the duplicated curve (leaving only low, middle, high, middle), selected what is now the new 1st vertex of the duplicated curve, as well as the last vertex of the original curve, and pressed <kbd>F</kbd> to join them.

If anyone knows of an easier way, please post.